# Error while compiling spark-jobserver

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, spark-jobserver

While refreshing my SBT project in IntelliJ IDEA, I am facing the following error:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[warn] Credentials file C:\Users\usr\.bintray\.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file C:\Users\usr\.bintray\.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file C:\Users\usr\.bintray\.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file C:\Users\usr\.bintray\.credentials does not exist
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last job-server-api/*:updateClassifiers' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last akka-app/*:updateClassifiers' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last job-server-extras/*:updateClassifiers' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last job-server/*:updateClassifiers' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last job-server-python/*:updateClassifiers' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last root/*:updateClassifiers' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last job-server-tests/*:updateClassifiers' for the full output.
[error] (job-server-api/*:updateClassifiers) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: classifiers cannot be empty
[error] (akka-app/*:updateClassifiers) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: classifiers cannot be empty
[error] (job-server-extras/*:updateClassifiers) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: classifiers cannot be empty
[error] (job-server/*:updateClassifiers) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: classifiers cannot be empty
[error] (job-server-python/*:updateClassifiers) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: classifiers cannot be empty
[error] (root/*:updateClassifiers) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: classifiers cannot be empty
[error] (job-server-tests/*:updateClassifiers) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: classifiers cannot be empty
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed May 9, 2017 8:01:21 PM
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="file:/C:/Users/usr/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/log/sbt.last.log">file:/C:/Users/usr/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/log/sbt.last.log</a>
```

I am trying to compile spark-jobserver code (spark-2.0-preview branch): https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/tree/spark-2.0-preview

Comment: This might seem simple but, have you tried and 'sbt clean compile' directly from the command line ?

Comment: I already tried that and I am able to compile successfully from the command line. However, that doesn't resolve the compilation errors in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Have you correctly configured your sbt project to automatically import like in this link : [see this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/getting-started-with-sbt.html#add_refresh_dependencies)

Comment: Yes, I am importing the project the same way. Also, I don't need to do any changes in the build.sbt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by passing "sources" classifier in transitiveClassifiers list:

```
transitiveClassifiers in Global := Seq("sources")
```

Earlier the list was empty in the build.sbt file:

```
transitiveClassifiers in Global := Seq()
```